# How to get new token.json for google apps script API (or google cloud platform) through Flask app

Tags: python, flask, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a flask app that I want to authenticate to use a google apps script API. If I create a token.json file with this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python) link it takes me to the authentication page and then creates a token.json file for me even if I've deleted it or its expired. This is what I want to do in my flask app (because tokens expire so I want to be able to refresh them). The code I'm using is

```
# Setup the Apps Script API scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

def getCredentialsAppScript():
    store = oauth_file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    return creds
```

then in getListItems (code snippet)

```
@app.route("/getListItems", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def getListItems():
    
    """Runs the sample.
    """
    SCRIPT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    creds = getCredentialsAppScript()

    service = build('script', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Create an execution request object.
    request = {"function": "getTokensForUser"}
```

the error simply says `UserWarning: Cannot access token.json: No such file or directory` what I don't understand is why I can't get a new token.json through the code block in the flask app but
when running the quickstart.py it takes me to the google sign-in page if I don't have a token.json.

```
if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may lack some information about [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) and [its implementation in Google API's](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2).

I would strongly encourage you to read [the documentation for Server side OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) there is even a [full example of an authorization, token revoke and API test call in **flask**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_5).

---

In specific the problem with your code is that you are copying the structure as the [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python) but you have to remember that the quickstart is meant to be executed as a command line program, not as a server side as Flask.

So because you are now in a server environment you first need to redirect the user to a google authorization page:

```py
# Copied from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_5

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
  # Create flow instance to manage the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow steps.
  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

  # The URI created here must exactly match one of the authorized redirect URIs
  # for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you configured in the API Console. If this
  # value doesn't match an authorized URI, you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch'
  # error.
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
      # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
      access_type='offline',
      # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
      include_granted_scopes='true')

  # Store the state so the callback can verify the auth server response.
  flask.session['state'] = state

  return flask.redirect(authorization_url)
```

And later receive  the authorization object in the `oauth2callback` function:

```py
# Copied from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_5
@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  # Specify the state when creating the flow in the callback so that it can
  # verified in the authorization server response.
  state = flask.session['state']

  flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
  flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)

  # Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
  authorization_response = flask.request.url
  flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)

  # Store credentials in the session.
  # ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
  #              credentials in a persistent database instead.
  credentials = flow.credentials
  flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

  return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('<Your function calling the API>'))
```